# Is there any solution regarding this error messege?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am facing this problem and I tried hard but can't solve this problem. This is so much important for me because my exam will start within 2 weeks. So please help me.

my code is here,

```
SELECT DISTINCT course_id FROM section 
WHERE semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009 AND course_id NOT IN(
    SELECT course_id 
    FROM section 
    WHERE semester = 'Spring' AND year = 2010);
```

My output is something like that,
[image]

I tried in different version of phpmyadmin and it's worked.
My database is here, 
[image: My database table]

Comment: The query in the question doesn't look like the query in the error message.

Comment: The error message says `NOT IN ( LIMIT 0, 25`. I don't see anything like that in the question.

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 1):

By default, PhpMyAdmin only shows the first 25 rows of results, and it does this by adding `LIMIT 0, 25` to the end of the query. It looks like it has a bug in the way it's adding this to your query, because it's putting it after `AND course_id NOT IN (` instead of putting it all the way at the end.

I guess this option is turned off in the other version of PhpMyAdmin, or the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Could simplify the above query this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT course_id FROM section course_id NOT IN(
    SELECT  course_id 
    FROM section 
    WHERE semester = 'Spring' AND year = 2010)
```

Comment: You're missing `WHERE`.

Comment: Your query is different. It's only supposed to return courses from Fall 2009 that don't have matches in Spring 2010.